# SQL Case Expression (Conditional)

Tags: sql

This is my CASE Expression:

```
case when count(distinct fcia.UserKey) > 1 and dd.FullDate between @CalcDate and @DefaultDate 
            then count(distinct fcia.UserKey)
else case when count(distinct fcia.UserKey) > 1 and dd.FullDate not between @CalcDate and @DefaultDate 
            then 0
else -1
end
end as StudentCount,
```

I would like to only display 1 condition, for example:

If the count > 1 and between the two dates then display

If the count > 1 and NOT BETWEEN dates then ONLY display if not equal to the above condition.

Lastly, else -1 if both conditions above do not equate.

Comment: Can you provide all your query please?

Comment: Query is too long unfortunatley

Comment: I _think_ you might want to use `GROUP BY ... HAVING CASE WHEN`, but then again you gave us next to no information, so I might be wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Your current attempt is close.  The correct syntax is:

```
CASE WHEN (condition1) THEN ... WHEN (condition2) THEN ... ELSE ... END
```

So use this `CASE` statement:

```
CASE WHEN COUNT(DISTINCT fcia.UserKey) > 1 AND
          dd.FullDate BETWEEN @CalcDate AND @DefaultDate 
     THEN COUNT(DISTINCT fcia.UserKey)
     WHEN COUNT(DISTINCT fcia.UserKey) > 1 AND
          dd.FullDate NOT BETWEEN @CalcDate AND @DefaultDate 
     THEN 0
     ELSE -1
END AS StudentCount
```

Comment: this still returns multiple rows. I would like the query to check for example : Does CASE 1 equate : yes, if not then check CASE 2 : does it equate? if not then use CASE 3

Comment: 8174124 Course Content 6 Content Folder/Content Area Content 21-08-16
8174124 Course Content 21 Content Folder/Content Area Content 21-08-16
8174124 Course Content 51 Content Folder/Content Area Content 21-08-16
8174124 Course Content 64 Content Folder/Content Area Content 21-08-16
8174124 Course Content 71 Content Folder/Content Area Content 21-08-16
8174124 Course Content 136 Content Folder/Content Area Content 21-08-16

Comment: this is an example of the output - you can see the only column that is not distinct is the student count, the other columns are distinct. i would expect the CASE to only display 1 condition..... If the count is between the dates then TAKE this, if no count between the dates then check outside of the dates, if nothing still then use -1

Comment: The `CASE` statement is fine, but your logic is not.  If you want to use a `CASE` statement to filter out records you will also need to use `GROUP BY` with `HAVING`.  Please post your full query along with sample data.